# Не собирается проект Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

Не определяется символ R. Все становится нормально, если убрать нижеуказанный файл.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="action_add_note"
        android:title="ADD NOTE"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />
</menu>
```

Иерархия: res> menu> menu_action_bar.xml. Папку menu я создал сам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел ошибку

```
android:id="@+id/action_add_note"
```

вместо

```
android:id="action_add_note"
```

Столько времени потерял